# Nested loops parsing huge object items freezes the browser at a certain thousand loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, coordinates, nested-loops

I've been trying to figure out how to improve the way my code calls a function with 3 given coords taken from a huge object. I'm using big objects with more than 3000 items on them so when executing the functions to retrieve a geodesic area the computer ends freezeing at a certain thousand loops.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{"coords":[
    {
        "latE6":42140202,
        "lngE6":1527653
    },
    {
        "latE6":42134147,
        "lngE6":1571707
    },
    {
        "latE6":42138114,
        "lngE6":1572871
    },
    {
        "latE6":42141407,
        "lngE6":1572997
    }]
}
```

I'm using 3 nested for-loops which works well with objects with less than 200-300 items, but when the object gets an elevated number of items browser ends up freezing and area can't be processed.

```
var x = data.coords.length;
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < x; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < x; k++) {
            //checks for duplicated coords
            //then calls geodesic area function
            //feeds new object tem with 3 coords info and result area
        }
    }
}
```

So long code works and if I remove the function call and add some debugging like count the amount of loops or so, it returns the amount of loops quite fast. But when it comes to call the function computer becomes slower and slower on each loop.

Extra info, there's the area calc function (taken from L.GeometryUtils.geodesicArea):

```
var calcArea = function(latLngs) {
    var pointsCount = latLngs.length,
        area = 0.0,
        d2r = Math.PI / 180,
        p1, p2;

    if (pointsCount > 2) {
        for (var i = 0; i < pointsCount; i++) {
            p1 = latLngs[i];
            p2 = latLngs[(i + 1) % pointsCount];
            area += ((p2.lng - p1.lng) * d2r) *
                (2 + Math.sin(p1.lat * d2r) + Math.sin(p2.lat * d2r));
        }
        area = area * 6378137.0 * 6378137.0 / 2.0;
        return Math.abs(area);
    }
};
```

What would be best way to execute all these million calculations? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If optimising your code is not enough and you need to perform heavy calculations, you could consider using web workers to perform the calculations in the background (similar to how you would code a multithreaded program) without blocking the UI.
See:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Apart from not blocking the browser ui, you can also parallelise parts of your calculations (if the kind of problem you're dealing with allows for it)